# Перестал выводить массив после введения данных

Tags: c++

Код не выводит после введения имени в case 2, причины так и не нашел, прошу помощи. case 2 после ввода и сравнения не выводи желаемый результат

```cpp
# include <iostream>
# include <conio.h>
# include <string.h>
# include <stdlib.h>
using namespace std;

struct cardfile
{
    char title[30];
    char director[25];
    int price;
};

int qcompare(const void* a, const void* b) 
{
    cardfile* aa = (cardfile*)a;
    cardfile* bb = (cardfile*)b;
    return aa->price - bb->price;
}

int main()
{
    char directorb[20];
    int n;
    int a = 1;
    int i;

    cout << "Enter amount of movies\n";
    cin >> n;
    cardfile* s = new cardfile[n];
    cout.setf(ios::left);

    cin.ignore();
    for (i = 0; i <= n - 1; i++)
    {
        cout << "Enter title\n";
        cin.getline(s[i].title, 30);

        cout << "Enter price\n";
        cin >> s[i].price;
        cin.ignore();

        cout << "Enter director name\n";
        cin.getline(s[i].director, 40);
    }

    cout << "Name                Director            Price\n";

    for (i = 0; i <= n - 1; i++)
    {
        cout.width(20); cout << s[i].title;
        cout.width(20); cout << s[i].director;
        cout.width(20); cout << s[i].price << "\n";
    }

    cout << "1 - Prices from low to high\n2 - Show film from director\n";
    while (a != 0)
    {
        cin >> a;
        switch (a)
        {
        case 1: 
        {
            cout << "Prices low to high\n";
            qsort(s, n, sizeof(cardfile), qcompare);

            cout << "Name                Director            Price\n";

            for (i = 0; i <= n - 1; i++)
            {
                cout.width(20); cout << s[i].title;
                cout.width(20); cout << s[i].director;
                cout.width(20); cout << s[i].price << "\n";
            }
            break;
        }
        case 2: {
            cout << "Enter director name\n";
            cin >> directorb;
            for (i = 0; i <= n - 1; i++)
            {
                if (strcmp(directorb, s[i].director) == 0) {
                    cout.width(20); cout << s[i].title;
                    cout.width(20); cout << s[i].price << "\n";
                }
            }
            break;
        }
            _getch();

        }
    }
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: @AlexGlebe     Можно ли поподробнее если можно, буду сильно благодарин

Comment: Не машайти си и с++! Если пишете на си, используйте для ввода/вывода printf, scanf, если c++, используйте для хранения строк string. std::cin не умеет работать с char[].

Answer (score 0):

```
/*
    cout << "Name                Director            Price\n";

    for (i = 0; i <= n - 1; i++)
    {
        cout.width(20); cout << s[i].title;
        cout.width(20); cout << s[i].director;
        cout.width(20); cout << s[i].price << "\n";
    }
*/
    cout << "3-show\n1 - Prices from low to high\n2 - Show film from director\n";
    while (a != 0)
    {
        cin >> a;
        switch (a)
        {
case 3 :
cout << "Name                Director            Price\n";

    for (i = 0; i <= n - 1; i++)
    {
        cout.width(20); cout << s[i].title;
        cout.width(20); cout << s[i].director;
        cout.width(20); cout << s[i].price << "\n";
    }
break;
```